# Would Lilith's pact with God be obsolete?

Tags: bible, abrahamic-religions, demons, judaism

God curses Lilith for her defiance in the Garden of Eden, and as such, Hebraic tradition depicts her as a temptress and slayer of children.

She eventually marries Asmodeus, himself a tempter and a demon of lust, and together they have demonic offspring to spread chaos throughout the world. Of those children, 100 of them must perish each day to satisfy Lilith's pact with God and the angels Senoy, Sansenoy, and Semangelof, who were tasked with bringing her back to Eden.

Wouldn't Lilith run out of offspring to have to kill eventually and God's punishment obsolete?